# SGS3 in app screen restarts

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, screen, reboot

I am having a problem with my Samsung Galaxy S3. I bought this last year. No damage so far. I usually download apps/games in Play store when all of a sudden I noticed my screen blacks out for a millisecond then restarts.

This usually happens in app/games when I play Smurfs and Sims, and even when I am using my camera and when I view the gallery. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Your assistance will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is probably the ["sudden death"](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2091045) issue experienced by several users. You could try updating your firmware to the latest firmware released by Samsung or flash a custom rom to fix the issue.